# Can any one tell me where i went wrong in this Jquery script

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on this example using `Jquery` to `End a session due to Inactivity` .

http://www.philpalmieri.com/js_sandbox/timedLogout/

In the available script I just changed a few things to redirect to my given `aspx` after `logout` as follows

```
$.fn.idleTimeout = function(options) {
var defaults = {
        inactivity: 1200000, //20 Minutes
        noconfirm: 10000, //10 Seconds
        sessionAlive: 30000, //10 Minutes
        //redirect_url: '/js_sandbox/',
        click_reset: true,
        //alive_url: '/js_sandbox/',
        //logout_url: '/js_sandbox/'
        logout_url: '/IdleTimeOut/Default2.aspx'
    }
```

But this is firing me an `undefined page` error after successful log out due to inactivity.

Also I have a few questions:

If I use this script and if I click ok on the prompt, that available, will session work all over my application? I am using `form authentication`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read documentation carefully. The `logout_url` option is an url for performing logout action on server whereas `redirect_url` is an url where user will be redirected after logout action executed. So far you need to uncomment `logout_url` option and set it's value to `'/IdleTimeOut/Default2.aspx'` and comment out the `logout_url` option if you don't need to executed logout action on server.

Comment: How can i increase time to some amount like 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

it already 20 minutes in your code :
inactivity: 1200000, //20 Minutes
To make it 5 minutes, it should be : inactivity: 300000, //5 Minutes